# Version Control - rewrite project branch

Tags: git, git-workflow

I have a project which has master and dev branches. Recently I figured out that I should completely rewrite the project in a different way than it is written now for performance and code readability reasons. 
My goal is to replace the master branch(working version) with the better version of the project. How do I do that? Do I just create a 'rewrite' branch and replace it with master when it's done?

Answer (score 0):

in git, branches are just pointers to revisions... which means that you can rename them at will at any time.... so yes, feel free to create a brand-new branch and then replace master (or any other branch for that matter) with the new one.